# Log4j nosql appender Failed to authenticate against MongoDB server

Tags: java, mongodb, maven, log4j2

I'm trying to use the [Apache Log4J NoSQL appender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.3/log4j-nosql/index.html). I've configured it to connect to my MongoDB instance, but I seem to be getting an authentication error when running the project with Maven Install:

```
ERROR Failed to authenticate against MongoDB server. Unknown error.
```

I am using MongoDB 3.0.4 and have created the following user with:

```
use test
db.createUser({
    user:"logUser",
    pwd:"pwd",
    roles:["readWrite","dbAdmin"]
})
```

And I already checked that I can connect using:

```
mongo -u logUser -p pwd
```

My log4j2.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="debug">
    <Appenders>
        <NoSql name="databaseAppender">
            <MongoDb databaseName="test" collectionName="logging" server = "localhost"
            port="27017" username = "logUser" password = "pwd"/>
        </NoSql>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="databaseAppender"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Following is my POM.xml configuration changes:

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.3</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-nosql</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>   
</dependencies>
```

Comment: can you try remove the `server` and `port` attributes and then see what happen? As you're using the default `localhost` and `port` for connecting to the DB so I don't think you need those.

Comment: It seems to be working in spite of the above error. But it was not working when using some other databaseName

Comment: what do you mean by not working? is it showing the same error? is the other database exists? can you access it using `mongo` client?

Comment: It was not logging anything to the database. Yes is shows the same error. The other database exists and is accessible using mongo client

Comment: A couple of factors which might affect it: 1: [authentication database](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-users/#user-authentication-database). Does the behaviour differ if, instead of using the _logUser_ user (who is defined in the _logging_ collection, you use a user defined in the _admin_ database who has rights to the _logging_ collection? 2: [authentication mechanism](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/authentication-mechanisms/). Is your user defined with MONGODB-CR or SCRAM-SHA1 authentication credentials, and does it make a difference if you switch them?